# Why the integration of Flutter with Unity and AR Vuforia makes no object appears?

Tags: unity-game-engine, flutter, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to integrate Flutter app with Unity and AR Vuforia. I tried to use library: flutter_unity_widget (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget).
When integrating Flutter app with Unity without Vuforia it works very well. But when I tried to use it with Vuforia … OK, I didn't get any error and I could build app, but when I tested it, it didn't show any object.

I did all the configuration with the library tutorial.

Maybe some of you integrated something like that?
Do you have any sample project with it?

Comment: Could you confirm your Unity version as well as the device with which you are testing?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved, we are coming across the same issue where Unity part builds and runs fine, but Vuforia fails to initialise. We are thinking it is to do with the Vuforia license location, or compression done by Flutter maybe at build, but are coming up against a lot of dead ends

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this blog about "[Building with Flutter + Unity (AR Experience Toolkit)](https://medium.com/potato/building-with-flutter-unity-ar-experience-toolkit-6aaf17dbb725)" for unity.

And for AR Vuforia, it seems that support for this is not yet materialized as of [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18508). You can watch out for the updates there.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me when I was testing on iOS, Android was OK
I went through all the steps, only that Vuforia didn't recognize anything. According to this issue [Dataset Foo could not be loaded and cannot be activated](https://github.com/juicycleff/flutter-unity-view-widget/issues/115#issuecomment-618891447), I dragged and dropped the data folder and Vuforia into the Runner.
And everything was working fine